# pandas divide two multi index series

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a multi-index series that looks like

```
            value
foo bar baz     
1   A    C    6
         D    2
    B    D    6
         F    4
2   B    C    5
         F    7
```

I would like to sum on foo and bar, to get the sum of values for each foo, bar, regardless of baz, which I can achieve with `df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()`. This series looks like:

```
        sum_value
foo bar      
1   A      8
    B      10
2   B      12
```

However, I would then like to divide the original `value` by the new `sum_value`, to get the percentage of baz, given foo and bar.

```
            value
foo bar baz     
1   A    C    6/8=.75
         D    2/8=.25
    B    D    6/10=.6
         F    4/10=.5
2   B    C    5/12=.42
         F    7/12=.58
```

I have tried `df.div(df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum())`, but get a Not Implemented error. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do it like this using `transform` to get sum with like indexes of oringal dataframe then use `div` with Pandas intrinsic data alignment:

```
df.div(df.groupby(['foo','bar']).transform('sum'))
```

Output:

```
                value
foo bar baz          
1   A   C    0.750000
        D    0.250000
    B   D    0.600000
        F    0.400000
2   B   C    0.416667
        F    0.583333
```

Comment: Just my 2 cent. Use `df.div(df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).transform('sum'))` if df is already a multiindex dataframe.

Comment: @LouisYang if your index levels are named, then you can use either the name or the level and it works the exact same.

Comment: This is probably new feature in pandas? The version I am using doesn't support it yet. But I am also using a quite old version.

Comment: Yes, [see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/whatsnew.html#groupby-enhancements).

Comment: No need to use `transform`, `df.div(df.groupby(['foo','bar']).sum())` is more efficient.

Comment: @FinThusiast You are absolutely right.  This is one of my earliest answers on SO about pandas.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [40]: df['value'] = df.reset_index('baz', drop=True).div(df.sum(level=[0,1])).values

In [41]: df
Out[41]:
                value
foo bar baz
1.0 A   C    0.750000
        D    0.250000
    B   D    0.600000
        F    0.400000
2.0 B   C    0.416667
        F    0.583333
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use the `transform` method of the `groupby` object:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas

data = StringIO("""\
foo bar baz value
1   A    C    6
1   A    D    2
1   B    D    6
1   B    F    4
2   B    C    5
2   B    F    7
""")
df = pandas.read_table(data, sep='\s+', index_col=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
result = df.div(df.groupby(level=['foo', 'bar']).transform('sum'))
print(result)

                value
foo bar baz          
1   A   C    0.750000
        D    0.250000
    B   D    0.600000
        F    0.400000
2   B   C    0.416667
        F    0.583333
```

Transform returns a series with the same index as the original dataframe:

```
print(df.groupby(level=['foo', 'bar']).transform('sum'))

                 value
foo bar baz       
1   A   C        8
        D        8
    B   D       10
        F       10
2   B   C       12
        F       12
```